# Floating tiny droplets in the water

Tags: water, safety, water-quality

Lately there seem to be floating tiny droplets (oil?) on the surface of tap water. This is limited to hot water, and does not affect other tenants in the building.

[image]

The water heater has just been replaced to try and address this issue to no avail.

What may be going on, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Some analysis of what kind of "oil" this is may help track down where it's coming from.  I think it's odd that you just threw a new water heater at this.  I cannot imagine how/why a water heater would produce oil.  Are there any pumps involved here?  Like a hot water circulating pump?  That could leak oil if it's failing.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks much for your comment. I'll look into it.